# Так всё-таки — вопиЕт или вопиёт?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, е-или-ё

*И даже не говорит, **а вопиёт. Вопиёт** о неискоренимом социальном холопстве «верхней» части либерального и традиционно беспамятного русского общества, которое в этом отношении превосходила лишь «высочайшая» власть.*
[В. Сиротин. Лермонтов и христианство](https://books.google.ee/books?id=wO8pDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT120&lpg=PT120&dq=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%91%D1%82&source=bl&ots=1Gj7Ev_iQG&sig=fQRDj5bVmjZ140OwYTU4B9ARxGs&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjal4-Z-bjdAhWLMewKHVJxBLQ4RhDoATABegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%91%D1%82&f=false)

*Большая боль не вопиет,* [**е** или **ё**?]
*Печаль всегда немногословна.

В горах безмолвно тает лед,

Пересыхает пруд безмолвно.*
[К. Кулиев. Большая боль не вопиет](http://lit.peoples.ru/poetry/kaysin_kuliev/poem_35915.shtml)

В школе (на факультативе "Мы любим поэзию") я слышала это стихотворение с **Ё** (педагог — заслуженный учитель ЭССР).
Неужели это было неправильно?

Answer (score 2):

Ну, Кулиев - переводной, не в счёт.

А "квалифицированные" словари требуют **е**, а не **ё**.

**[ВОПИЯ́ТЬ](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/03/sl406404.htm?cmd=p&istext=1)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примеры предложений, как пишется *[вопиет](https://xn----8sbhebeda0a3c5a7a.xn--p1ai/%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%82/)*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Ну, Кулиев - переводной, не в счёт.* — Ну а разве Н.Гребнев (Рамбах) плохой поэт/переводчик? Или, можно подумать, его книги никто не редактировал (в советские-то времена)?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что словарь Ушакова предлагает писать через **-ё-**, и что в многочисленных изданиях находится такое же написание, можно предположить, что в за последние сто лет здесь произошли какие-то изменения. Но более определённой информации найти не удалось.

Comment: Ну, не за сто лет, конечно! К. Кулиев родился в 1917 году, стихотворение написано в 1966. P. S. Согласна с Вашим комментарием по поводу советской редактуры.